# Dúvida contanto ao cálculo da área

Tags: python, processamento-de-imagens

Estava testando um algoritmo que me retorna a área de objetos com base em uma referência, a priori este me dava resultados bastante próximos ao real, quando a referência estava a mesma altura do objeto medido, porém resolvi observar em uma altura diferente, com isso verifiquei que a área dada era maior que eu esperava.

[image: Referência é o circulo a esquerda e o objeto esta a direita sobre o tubo de 11cm de diâmetro]

Referência é o circulo a esquerda e o objeto esta a direita sobre o tubo de 11cm de diâmetro.

Imaginei que era devido a curvatura do tubo, mas como deu bastante alta imaginei que foi devido a proximidade da câmera, e  como estou utilizando um método de contagem de pixel pode ter ocorrido este problema.

Gostaria de saber se existe outro meio de obter esta área sem ser pela contagem dos pixels ou alguma forma de reverter esta diferença?

Comment: Poste o código que você usa e explique como você faz o cálculo. Se o seu objeto de referência não mudou de tamanho, não há por que parar de funcionar (se você fez direitinho: sabendo o tamanho do objeto de referência em cm, basta encontrá-lo na imagem e medir o tamanho dele em pixels para conhecer a "escala" em que a imagem se encontra; essa mesma proporção então é aplicada ao novo objeto que você quer medir, e é por isso que existe o objeto de referência).

Comment: Obviamente a proximidade de um objeto com a câmera fará com que ele fique maior. Seu cálculo vale somente com capturas em condições semelhantes, objetos à mesma distância. A câmera não consegue capturar a distância entre os objetos no eixo Z.

Comment: Além disso, o que você quer dizer com "altura diferente"? Se os objetos não foram fotografados pela mesma câmera e à mesma distância (como disse o colega @CelsoMarigoJr), não faz sentido aplicar essa proporção.

Comment: altura diferente eu quis dizer que o que eu queria medir estava sobre outro objeto.

Comment: mas realmente não havia pensado nessa discrepância com o eixo Z, vou refazer o meu código aqui, obrigado pela ajuda Celso Marigo e Luiz Vieira

Comment: Por nada. Lembre-se que se os objetos estiverem em distância diferentes, a proporção (pixel-na-imagem x cm-na-vida-real) não se aplica porque eles não estão mais na mesma "escala" (de tamanho na imagem, mesmo). Se você tivesse duas câmeras você até poderia tentar estimar tamanho com base nas distâncias calculadas com relação ao efeito [Parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax#Distance_measurement), mas é mais usual (e mais fácil) manter a câmera única perpendicular à cena e os itens (referência e interesse) à mesma distância.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado

Comment: Por nada. Eu votei pra fechar como fora do escopo porque não tem muito o que responder envolvendo programação, na verdade. Além disso, uma possível sugestão do problema já te foi dada em comentários. Mas se o problema for algo diferente, edite-a ou abra uma nova pergunta. :)